# How to remove rest of Delta Monitor 1500 shower handle?

Tags: plumbing, shower, cartridge, delta

[image]

The complete album of images is here https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MZWV.jpg
I have removed all of the screws and the nut shown in the picture but I can’t manage to pop off the rest of the handle to get to the cartridge. I am trying to remove the handle so I can update it to a 1700 series handle. I found a similar post here but the detail of how to remove the handle we’re not provided.

Comment: I think a good start would be to get some CLR and work it into all the cracks and holes. Those sleeves should just slide / twist off...... gentle prying..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried one of these?

[image]

These are used for removing pulleys from shafts.  You are likely going to need to sharpen the points to fit.  With a 3 jaw puller it's often useful to wrap a stretchy cord around the jaws to keep them from slipping off a narrow edge.  The end is either a 1/2" or 9/16 end.  use a socket on it.

Comment: I was able to borrow a 2 jaw puller from a coworker. That did the trick, thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

That's a tricky one, that back bracket is supposed to be screwed to a board, then the front part just unscrews. but without the board there pipes are likely to break if you try too hard to unscrew it.